# Alternative to V$LOCKED_OBJECT for finding locked tables

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

V$VERSION: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

```
select count(*)
INTO n_count
from V$LOCKED_OBJECT a
inner join ALL_OBJECTS o
on a.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
where o.OBJECT_TYPE = v_object_type
and o.OBJECT_NAME = p_table_name;
```

The fragment above is part of a function called during batch processing looking for table locks.

SESSION_ROLES shows the application ID has SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE. SELECT_ANY_DICTIONARY privilege was temporarily granted to the application ID to create the function.

So, we can SELECT on V$LOCKED_OBJECT, but cannot compile an object that references it without involving a different group to temporarily grant the SELECT_ANY_DICTIONARY privilege.

The issue is that deploys can make the function invalid, but the DBA cannot recompile it without the additional privilege.

Using "execute immediate" we can compile the function, but get "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" at runtime, indicating it also expects the additional privilege. Note that when running the same "execute immediate" in a TOAD session it runs as expected. It is only running the function with it that causes the error.

Are there any other options within the application itself to determine if a table is locked?

Comment: Would it be possible for whatever group temporarily grants `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` to permanently grant whatever user owns the procedure `SELECT` access on just `V$LOCKED_OBJECT`?  Since this is a political problem rather than a technical problem, it is hard to know what objections are being raised and what alternatives might be acceptable.

Comment: @Justin Cave, thank you for your help. We have SELECT access via SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE. What we need to be able to do (during production deploys) is to compile an object with V$LOCKED_OBJECT. We can add the responsible group to our Change Request, but their SLA is two days longer than our DBA group and adds complexity to the process. Not a deal-killer, but inconvenient.

Comment: I get that.  My confusion is why you're allowed to have the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` granted to whatever user owns the procedure permanently but you can only have the essentially equivalent `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege granted temporarily.  I assume you've asked that `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` be granted permanently and were denied for some reason.  You could ask that `SELECT` access be granted on `V$LOCKED_OBJECT` permanently which might address whatever objection was raised to the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` grant.  Or you could create an invoker's rights procedure.

Comment: @Justin Cave, best guess is SELECT_ANY_DICTIONARY is a system privelege, while SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE is a more restricted role. There is an ongoing policy review, so we might lose the role in the future. Well above my pay grade. 

The current issue is compile, not select. We do have a work around, but it is inconvenient and subject to delays during a production deploy.

Comment: A definer's rights stored procedure cannot make use of privileges granted through a role.  So that's why the object doesn't compile without `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`.  The system privilege `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` is basically identical to the role `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` in terms of privileges-- they're intended as replacements.  You can ask for just to grant you need, which is `SELECT` on `V$LOCKED_OBJECT` which would allow you to compile the procedure.  You could make the procedure an invoker's rights procedure which can make use of roles but requires the caller to have privileges.

Comment: @Justin Cave, thank you. I'll reach out to our DBA and try.